# LWJGL 2 - Always show front of 3D font

Tags: java, lwjgl

I'm trying to always show the front of a 3D font to the user. I tried rotating the font when rotating the camera, but never could get it to work.

I currently have this:
[image]

I'm trying to do this (font always faces front):
[image]

TrueTypeFont.java

```
package com.displee.render.font;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBuffer;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferByte;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * A TrueType font implementation originally for Slick, edited for Bobjob's Engine
 * @original author James Chambers (Jimmy)
 * @original author Jeremy Adams (elias4444)
 * @original author Kevin Glass (kevglass)
 * @original author Peter Korzuszek (genail)
 * @new version edited by David Aaron Muhar (bobjob)
 */
public class TrueTypeFont {

    public final static int ALIGN_LEFT = 0, ALIGN_RIGHT = 1, ALIGN_CENTER = 2;
    /**
     * Array that holds necessary information about the font characters
     */
    private IntObject[] charArray = new IntObject[256];

    /**
     * Map of user defined font characters (Character <-> IntObject)
     */
    private Map customChars = new HashMap();

    /**
     * Boolean flag on whether AntiAliasing is enabled or not
     */
    private boolean antiAlias;

    /**
     * Font's size
     */
    private int fontSize = 0;

    /**
     * Font's height
     */
    private int fontHeight = 0;

    /**
     * Texture used to cache the font 0-255 characters
     */
    private int fontTextureID;

    /**
     * Default font texture width
     */
    private int textureWidth = 512;

    /**
     * Default font texture height
     */
    private int textureHeight = 512;

    /**
     * A reference to Java's AWT Font that we create our font texture from
     */
    private Font font;

    /**
     * The font metrics for our Java AWT font
     */
    private FontMetrics fontMetrics;


    private int correctL = 9, correctR = 8;

    private class IntObject {

        /**
         * Character's width
         */
        public int width;

        /**
         * Character's height
         */
        public int height;

        /**
         * Character's stored x position
         */
        public int storedX;

        /**
         * Character's stored y position
         */
        public int storedY;
    }


    public TrueTypeFont(Font font, boolean antiAlias, char[] additionalChars) {
        this.font = font;
        this.fontSize = font.getSize() + 3;
        this.antiAlias = antiAlias;

        createSet(additionalChars);

        fontHeight -= 1;
        if (fontHeight <= 0) {
            fontHeight = 1;
        }
    }

    public TrueTypeFont(Font font, boolean antiAlias) {
        this(font, antiAlias, null);
    }

    public void setCorrection(boolean on) {
        if (on) {
            correctL = 2;
            correctR = 1;
        } else {
            correctL = 0;
            correctR = 0;
        }
    }

    private BufferedImage getFontImage(char ch) {
        // Create a temporary image to extract the character's size
        BufferedImage tempfontImage = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) tempfontImage.getGraphics();
        if (antiAlias == true) {
            g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        }
        g.setFont(font);
        fontMetrics = g.getFontMetrics();
        int charwidth = fontMetrics.charWidth(ch) + 8;

        if (charwidth <= 0) {
            charwidth = 7;
        }
        int charheight = fontMetrics.getHeight() + 3;
        if (charheight <= 0) {
            charheight = fontSize;
        }

        // Create another image holding the character we are creating
        BufferedImage fontImage;
        fontImage = new BufferedImage(charwidth, charheight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D gt = (Graphics2D) fontImage.getGraphics();
        if (antiAlias == true) {
            gt.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        }
        gt.setFont(font);

        gt.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        int charx = 3;
        int chary = 1;
        gt.drawString(String.valueOf(ch), (charx), (chary) + fontMetrics.getAscent());
        //fontImage = ImageUtils.flipVertically(fontImage);
        //fontImage = ImageUtils.flipHorizontally(fontImage);
        //fontImage = ImageUtils.flipHorizontallyAndVertically(fontImage);
        return fontImage;

    }

    private void createSet(char[] customCharsArray) {
        // If there are custom chars then I expand the font texture twice
        if (customCharsArray != null && customCharsArray.length > 0) {
            textureWidth *= 2;
        }

        // In any case this should be done in other way. Texture with size 512x512
        // can maintain only 256 characters with resolution of 32x32. The texture
        // size should be calculated dynamicaly by looking at character sizes.

        try {

            BufferedImage imgTemp = new BufferedImage(textureWidth, textureHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) imgTemp.getGraphics();

            g.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, 1));
            g.fillRect(0, 0, textureWidth, textureHeight);

            int rowHeight = 0;
            int positionX = 0;
            int positionY = 0;

            int customCharsLength = (customCharsArray != null) ? customCharsArray.length : 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < 256 + customCharsLength; i++) {

                // get 0-255 characters and then custom characters
                char ch = (i < 256) ? (char) i : customCharsArray[i - 256];

                BufferedImage fontImage = getFontImage(ch);

                IntObject newIntObject = new IntObject();

                newIntObject.width = fontImage.getWidth();
                newIntObject.height = fontImage.getHeight();

                if (positionX + newIntObject.width >= textureWidth) {
                    positionX = 0;
                    positionY += rowHeight;
                    rowHeight = 0;
                }

                newIntObject.storedX = positionX;
                newIntObject.storedY = positionY;

                if (newIntObject.height > fontHeight) {
                    fontHeight = newIntObject.height;
                }

                if (newIntObject.height > rowHeight) {
                    rowHeight = newIntObject.height;
                }

                // Draw it here
                g.drawImage(fontImage, positionX, positionY, null);

                positionX += newIntObject.width;

                if (i < 256) { // standard characters
                    charArray[i] = newIntObject;
                } else { // custom characters
                    customChars.put(new Character(ch), newIntObject);
                }

                fontImage = null;
            }

            fontTextureID = loadImage(imgTemp);


            //.getTexture(font.toString(), imgTemp);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Failed to create font.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void drawQuad(float drawX, float drawY, float drawX2, float drawY2, float srcX, float srcY, float srcX2, float srcY2, float z) {
        float DrawWidth = drawX2 - drawX;
        float DrawHeight = drawY2 - drawY;
        float TextureSrcX = srcX / textureWidth;
        float TextureSrcY = srcY / textureHeight;
        float SrcWidth = srcX2 - srcX;
        float SrcHeight = srcY2 - srcY;
        float RenderWidth = (SrcWidth / textureWidth);
        float RenderHeight = (SrcHeight / textureHeight);

        GL11.glTexCoord2f(TextureSrcX, TextureSrcY);
        GL11.glVertex3f(drawX, drawY, z);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(TextureSrcX, TextureSrcY + RenderHeight);
        GL11.glVertex3f(drawX, drawY + DrawHeight, z);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(TextureSrcX + RenderWidth, TextureSrcY + RenderHeight);
        GL11.glVertex3f(drawX + DrawWidth, drawY + DrawHeight, z);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(TextureSrcX + RenderWidth, TextureSrcY);
        GL11.glVertex3f(drawX + DrawWidth, drawY, z);
    }

    public int getWidth(String whatchars) {
        int totalwidth = 0;
        IntObject intObject = null;
        int currentChar = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < whatchars.length(); i++) {
            currentChar = whatchars.charAt(i);
            if (currentChar < 256) {
                intObject = charArray[currentChar];
            } else {
                intObject = (IntObject) customChars.get(new Character((char) currentChar));
            }

            if (intObject != null) {
                totalwidth += intObject.width;
            }
        }
        return totalwidth;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return fontHeight;
    }


    public int getHeight(String HeightString) {
        return fontHeight;
    }

    public int getLineHeight() {
        return fontHeight;
    }

    public void drawString(float x, float y, float z, String whatchars, float scaleX, float scaleY) {
        drawString(x, y, z, whatchars, 0, whatchars.length() - 1, scaleX, scaleY, ALIGN_LEFT);
    }

    public void drawString(float x, float y, float z, String whatchars, float scaleX, float scaleY, int format) {
        drawString(x, y, z, whatchars, 0, whatchars.length() - 1, scaleX, scaleY, format);
    }


    public void drawString(float x, float y, float z, String whatchars, int startIndex, int endIndex, float scaleX, float scaleY, int format) {

        IntObject intObject = null;
        int charCurrent;


        int totalwidth = 0;
        int i = startIndex, d, c;
        float startY = 0;


        switch (format) {
            case ALIGN_RIGHT: {
                d = -1;
                c = correctR;

                while (i < endIndex) {
                    if (whatchars.charAt(i) == '\n') {
                        startY -= fontHeight;
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                break;
            }
            case ALIGN_CENTER: {
                for (int l = startIndex; l <= endIndex; l++) {
                    charCurrent = whatchars.charAt(l);
                    if (charCurrent == '\n') {
                        break;
                    }
                    if (charCurrent < 256) {
                        intObject = charArray[charCurrent];
                    } else {
                        intObject = (IntObject) customChars.get(new Character((char) charCurrent));
                    }
                    totalwidth += intObject.width - correctL;
                }
                totalwidth /= -2;
            }
            case ALIGN_LEFT:
            default: {
                d = 1;
                c = correctL;
                break;
            }

        }

        java.util.List<QuadObject> list = new ArrayList<>(endIndex - startIndex);

        while (i >= startIndex && i <= endIndex) {

            charCurrent = whatchars.charAt(i);
            if (charCurrent < 256) {
                intObject = charArray[charCurrent];
            } else {
                intObject = (IntObject) customChars.get(new Character((char) charCurrent));
            }

            if (intObject != null) {
                if (d < 0) {
                    totalwidth += (intObject.width - c) * d;
                }
                if (charCurrent == '\n') {
                    startY -= fontHeight * d;
                    totalwidth = 0;
                    if (format == ALIGN_CENTER) {
                        for (int l = i + 1; l <= endIndex; l++) {
                            charCurrent = whatchars.charAt(l);
                            if (charCurrent == '\n') {
                                break;
                            }
                            if (charCurrent < 256) {
                                intObject = charArray[charCurrent];
                            } else {
                                intObject = (IntObject) customChars.get(new Character((char) charCurrent));
                            }
                            totalwidth += intObject.width - correctL;
                        }
                        totalwidth /= -2;
                    }
                    //if center get next lines total width/2;
                } else {
                    QuadObject quad = new QuadObject((totalwidth + intObject.width) * scaleX + x, startY * scaleY + y, totalwidth * scaleX + x, (startY + intObject.height) * scaleY + y, intObject.storedX + intObject.width, intObject.storedY + intObject.height, intObject.storedX, intObject.storedY, z);
                    list.add(quad);
                    if (d > 0) {
                        totalwidth += (intObject.width - c) * d;
                    }
                }
                i += d;

            }
        }

        float centerX = 0;
        for(QuadObject quad : list) {
            centerX += quad.drawX + (quad.drawX2 - quad.drawX);
        }
        centerX /= 2.0f;
        float centerY = 0;
        for(QuadObject quad : list) {
            centerY += quad.drawY + (quad.drawY2 - quad.drawY);
        }
        centerY /= 2.0f;

        //GL11.glTranslatef( -centerX, -centerY, -z);
        //GL11.glTranslatef(0, 0, -z);
        GL11.glRotatef(-Test3DFont.rotation.x, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        GL11.glRotatef(-Test3DFont.rotation.y, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        //GL11.glRotatef(-Test3DFont.rotation.z, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        //GL11.glTranslatef(0, 0, z);
        //GL11.glTranslatef(centerX, centerY, z); // M1 - 2nd translation

        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D); // Enable Texture Mapping
        GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, fontTextureID);
        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
        for(QuadObject quad : list) {
            drawQuad(quad.drawX, quad.drawY, quad.drawX2, quad.drawY2, quad.srcX, quad.srcY, quad.srcX2, quad.srcY2, quad.z);
        }
        GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        GL11.glEnd();
        GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    }

    public static int loadImage(BufferedImage bufferedImage) {
        try {
            short width = (short) bufferedImage.getWidth();
            short height = (short) bufferedImage.getHeight();
            //textureLoader.bpp = bufferedImage.getColorModel().hasAlpha() ? (byte)32 : (byte)24;
            int bpp = (byte) bufferedImage.getColorModel().getPixelSize();
            ByteBuffer byteBuffer;
            DataBuffer db = bufferedImage.getData().getDataBuffer();
            if (db instanceof DataBufferInt) {
                int intI[] = ((DataBufferInt) (bufferedImage.getData().getDataBuffer())).getData();
                byte newI[] = new byte[intI.length * 4];
                for (int i = 0; i < intI.length; i++) {
                    byte b[] = intToByteArray(intI[i]);
                    int newIndex = i * 4;

                    newI[newIndex] = b[1];
                    newI[newIndex + 1] = b[2];
                    newI[newIndex + 2] = b[3];
                    newI[newIndex + 3] = b[0];
                }

                byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(width * height * (bpp / 8)).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).put(newI);
            } else {
                byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(width * height * (bpp / 8)).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).put(((DataBufferByte) (bufferedImage.getData().getDataBuffer())).getData());
            }
            byteBuffer.flip();


            int internalFormat = GL11.GL_RGBA8, format = GL11.GL_RGBA;
            IntBuffer textureId = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);
            ;
            GL11.glGenTextures(textureId);
            GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId.get(0));


            GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL11.GL_CLAMP);
            GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL11.GL_CLAMP);

            GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL11.GL_LINEAR);
            GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL11.GL_LINEAR);

            GL11.glTexEnvf(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL11.GL_MODULATE);


            GL11.glTexImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, internalFormat, width, height, 0, format, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()));
            return textureId.get(0);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        return -1;
    }

    public static boolean isSupported(String fontname) {
        Font font[] = getFonts();
        for (int i = font.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (font[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase(fontname)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static Font[] getFonts() {
        return GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAllFonts();
    }

    public static byte[] intToByteArray(int value) {
        return new byte[]{(byte) (value >>> 24), (byte) (value >>> 16), (byte) (value >>> 8), (byte) value};
    }

    public void destroy() {
        IntBuffer scratch = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);
        scratch.put(0, fontTextureID);
        GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
        GL11.glDeleteTextures(scratch);
    }

    @AllArgsConstructor
    private class QuadObject {
        private float drawX;
        private float drawY;
        private float drawX2;
        private float drawY2;
        private float srcX;
        private float srcY;
        private float srcX2;
        private float srcY2;
        private float z;
    }
}
```

Test3DFont.java

```
package com.displee.render.font;
import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.input.Mouse;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.util.glu.GLU;
import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector3f;

import java.awt.*;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.util.glu.GLU.gluPerspective;

public class Test3DFont {

    private static final int WIDTH = 800;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 600;

    private static final float FOV = 45f;
    private static final float NEAR = 0.1f;
    private static final float FAR = 1000f;

    private static boolean mousePressed;
    private static Vector3f startCoordinations = new Vector3f();
    private static float scale = 0.05f;

    public static Vector3f rotation = new Vector3f(0, 0, 0);
    private static Vector3f startRotation = new Vector3f();

    private static TrueTypeFont font;

    private static boolean running = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        initializeDisplay();
        font = new TrueTypeFont(new Font("serif", Font.PLAIN, 30), true);
        initializeGL();
        while(running) {
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
            handleMouse();

            font.drawString(0, 0, 0, "Test", 0.1f, 0.1f);

            loadDefaultRotation();
            setViewport();

            drawGrid();
            Display.sync(60);
            Display.update();

            if (Display.isCloseRequested()) {
                break;
            }
        }
        font.destroy();
        Display.destroy();
    }

    private static void initializeDisplay() throws LWJGLException {
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        Display.create();
        setViewport();
    }

    public static void set2DMode() {
        //GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);                        // Select The Projection Matrix
        GL11.glPushMatrix();                                     // Store The Projection Matrix
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();                                   // Reset The Projection Matrix
        GL11.glOrtho(0, WIDTH, 0, HEIGHT, -1, 1);                          // Set Up An Ortho Screen
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);                         // Select The Modelview Matrix
        GL11.glPushMatrix();                                     // Store The Modelview Matrix
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();                                   // Reset The Modelview Matrix
    }

    public static void set3DMode() {
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);                        // Select The Projection Matrix
        GL11.glPopMatrix();                                      // Restore The Old Projection Matrix
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);                         // Select The Modelview Matrix
        GL11.glPopMatrix();                                      // Restore The Old Projection Matrix
        //GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    }

    private static void setViewport() {
        glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluPerspective(FOV, (float) WIDTH / (float) HEIGHT, NEAR, FAR);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    }

    private static void initializeGL() {
        glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
        glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glCullFace(GL_BACK);
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    }

    private static void handleMouse() {
        scale += Mouse.getDWheel() > 0 ? 0.005f : Mouse.getDWheel() < 0 ? -0.005f : 0;
        int x = Mouse.getY();
        int y = Mouse.getX();
        if (!mousePressed) {
            mousePressed = Mouse.isButtonDown(0);
            if (mousePressed) {
                startCoordinations.set((float) x, (float) y, 0.0f);
                startRotation = new Vector3f(rotation);
            }
        } else if (!Mouse.isButtonDown(0)) {
            mousePressed = false;
        }
        if (!mousePressed) {
            return;
        }
        float differenceX = x - startCoordinations.x;
        float differenceY = y - startCoordinations.y;
        rotation.set(startRotation.x - (differenceX * 0.5F), startRotation.y + (differenceY * 0.5F), 0);
    }

    private static void loadDefaultRotation() {
        glLoadIdentity();
        Vector3f cameraPosition = new Vector3f();
        glTranslatef(cameraPosition.x, cameraPosition.y, -10);
        glRotatef(rotation.x, 1.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F);
        glRotatef(rotation.y, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F);
        glRotatef(rotation.z, 0.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F);
        glScalef(scale, scale, scale);
    }

    private static void drawGrid() {
        glColor4f(0.7176471f, 0.7176471f, 0.7176471f, 1.0f);
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        float size = 50;
        float step = 10;
        for (float i = -size; i <= size; i += step) {
            glVertex3f(i, 0, size);
            glVertex3f(i, 0, -size);
            glVertex3f(size, 0, i);
            glVertex3f(-size, 0, i);
        }
        glEnd();
    }

    public static int[] getScreenCoords(double x, double y, double z) {
        FloatBuffer screenCoords = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(4);
        IntBuffer viewport = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(16);
        FloatBuffer modelView = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
        FloatBuffer projection = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
        GL11.glGetFloat(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelView);
        GL11.glGetFloat(GL11.GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection);
        GL11.glGetInteger(GL11.GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);
        boolean result = GLU.gluProject((float) x, (float) y, (float) z, modelView, projection, viewport, screenCoords);
        if (result) {
            return new int[] { (int) screenCoords.get(0), (int) screenCoords.get(1) };
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Can anyone help me with this? How can I make it so I always see the front of the font?

**Update 1:**
I've got it almost working by rotating the quads. I've added the following code in the `drawString` method before enabling texture 2D:

```
GL11.glRotatef(-Test3DFont.rotation.x, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
GL11.glRotatef(-Test3DFont.rotation.y, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
```

I've updated the code. It currently looks like this:
[image]

Comment: In the example gif, the text is rendered on screenspace rather than 3D space. The 3D location is translated to 2D space in order to draw them in the right spots. You might can search for how to render sprites if you want the text to be rendered in 3D space instead.

Comment: I got it almost working by rotating the quads. But its not perfect yet. The font disappears when looking from above. I've also updated the code.

Comment: Shouldn't the rotation axis be (1, 0, 0) for the X rotation instead of (0, 0, 0) as it currently is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed it by pushing a matrix and using the original x, y and z coords in the translation. I also had to subtract `180` from the rotation because that's my starting rotation. Ended up with the following code:

```
    GL11.glPushMatrix();
    GL11.glTranslatef(x, y, z);
    GL11.glRotatef(180 - rotation.y, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    GL11.glTranslatef(-x, -y, -z);

    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D); // Enable Texture Mapping
    GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, fontTextureID);
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
    for(QuadObject quad : list) {
        drawQuad(quad.drawX, quad.drawY, quad.drawX2, quad.drawY2, quad.srcX, quad.srcY, quad.srcX2, quad.srcY2, quad.z);
    }
    GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    GL11.glEnd();
    GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    GL11.glPopMatrix();
```